# Changing SQL syntax in QGIS Virtual Layers

Tags: qgis, sql, virtual-layer

I am experiencing difficulties with SQL syntax in a Virtual Layer. I can do the simplest query form such as:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
```

and this displays on my canvas.

However, if I try to name fields in my table such as:

```sql
SELECT field1, field2
FROM mytable
```

this doesn't create an error but does not display on my canvas.

Can anyone offer suggestions, please? I have tried it on several layers.

Comment: Are you getting something like?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/328990/qgis-bad-allocation-when-trying-to-view-table-from-virtual-layer-sql

Comment: If none of **field1** or **field2** is a geometry fields nothings will appear on the map canvas ... is that what u mean ? What kind of query do u intend to do ?

Answer (score 5):

For virtual layers, the actual geometry of the features are in a column named `geometry`.

In your first query when you select all columns, you are implicitly selecting the geometry column. That's why you can see the features on the canvas.

In the second query, you are only selecting non-spatial columns (field1, field2 etc.) and they show up as a table. To fix that, update your query like below

```
SELECT field1, field2, geometry
FROM mytable
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I hadn't realised that a geometry field is required in the syntax. This solves my problem. Well done.